# how to get the textbox value entered and call the function on keypress in ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying this in SSJS. I have a textbox. What I need is when the user enters any data in the textbox I need to take that value, search in the DE and display a list of matching data.

So how can I capture the value and pass the value in the search parameter?

Any HELP is really appreciated.
Lalit

```
<script runat=server>  

   function getValuetxtbox()
   {
       Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

                var company_name_de = DataExtension.Init("DE_name");  
                var filter_criteria = {Property:"FirstName",SimpleOperator:"Equals",Value:"textbox1.value;"};
       var results = company_name_de.Rows.Retrieve(filter_criteria);

       Write("<datalist id='CompanyName'>");

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    Write("<option value=" + results[i].FirstName + ">"+ results[i].FirstName +"</option>");
                    }
     Write("</datalist>");
   }
   </script>

      <input type='text' name='textbox1' onKeyPress='getValuetxtbox()' />
```

Answer (score 1):

SSJS is a server side script so you won't be able to call it from the front end like standard javascript you would typically need to reload the page and pass the value via a URL parameter or form POST.

The easiest way you can access the URL or form POST parameter is with AMPscript and access that value with SSJS.

```
%%[ Var @Value Set @Value = RequestParameter('key') ]%%

<script runat="server">
var value = Variable.GetValue('@Value');
</script>
```

You obviously wouldn't want to reload the page after every key press so creating a submit button would be the easiest option if that suits. Alternatively you could try an AJAX solution ([example](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000IBdXQAW)) that calls a seperate CloudPage with the SSJS script but not sure if thats what you are wanting and would be a little tricky to setup if its possible.